# Type a ":" in Emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs

I can't type a ":" in Emacs minubuffer, spacifically to enter /ssh:something, it hangs as soon as I type ":" (GNU Emacs 24.5.1, clean `emacs -q`).

How can I enter a ":" in Emacs minibuffer?

Comment: Consider providing a step-by-step recipe starting with `emacs -Q`. (Sounds like Tramp is waiting for a password or something.)

Comment: 1-Launch Emacs 24.5.1 with `emacs -q` 2 - type `C-C-f ` 3 - type "/ssh:" when you enter ":" emacs hangs. Same with "/sudo:"

Comment: I recommend you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.